# kubect exec getting error after upgrading rancher to 2.7.3

Tags: rancher

getting following error while running kubectl exec command after upgrading rancher from 2.6.6 to 2.7.3

$ k exec -it -n camunda-test nginx-7cccf59bc7-kl6dl -- bash
Error from server:

$ k exec -v=7 -it -n camunda-test nginx-7cccf59bc7-kl6dl -- bash
I0802 12:45:14.763654   47866 loader.go:373] Config loaded from file:  /Users/jitan.sahu/.kube/config
I0802 12:45:14.769316   47866 round_trippers.go:463] GET https://ce-rancher27.dsbu.cloud/k8s/clusters/c-k4lpt/api/v1/namespaces/camunda-test/pods/nginx-7cccf59bc7-kl6dl
I0802 12:45:14.769331   47866 round_trippers.go:469] Request Headers:
I0802 12:45:14.769342   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0802 12:45:14.769349   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.27.4 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/fa3d799
I0802 12:45:14.769356   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     Authorization: Bearer 
I0802 12:45:15.848632   47866 round_trippers.go:574] Response Status: 200 OK in 1079 milliseconds
I0802 12:45:15.851207   47866 podcmd.go:76] Defaulting container name from annotation container-0
I0802 12:45:15.851542   47866 round_trippers.go:463] POST https://ce-rancher27.dsbu.cloud/k8s/clusters/c-k4lpt/api/v1/namespaces/camunda-test/pods/nginx-7cccf59bc7-kl6dl/exec?command=bash&container=container-0&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=true
I0802 12:45:15.851558   47866 round_trippers.go:469] Request Headers:
I0802 12:45:15.851568   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.27.4 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/fa3d799
I0802 12:45:15.851576   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io
I0802 12:45:15.851584   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v3.channel.k8s.io
I0802 12:45:15.851591   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v2.channel.k8s.io
I0802 12:45:15.851603   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: channel.k8s.io
I0802 12:45:15.851612   47866 round_trippers.go:473]     Authorization: Bearer 
I0802 12:45:16.570536   47866 round_trippers.go:574] Response Status: 403 Forbidden in 718 milliseconds
I0802 12:45:16.571179   47866 helpers.go:246] server response object: [{
"metadata": {}
}]
Error from server:

following command to work

kubectl exec -it -n camunda-test nginx-7cccf59bc7-kl6dl -- bash